# LibGDX Failed to create Project

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I cannot create a new libgdx project with the gdx-setup.jar. It tells me the BUILD FAILED when I checked advanced > eclipse to use it in eclipse. It tells me the following:

```
Generating app in D:\programmierung\libgdx\test
Executing 'D:\programmierung\libgdx\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon eclipse afterEclipseImport'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
:core:clean
:desktop:clean UP-TO-DATE
:html:clean UP-TO-DATE
:eclipseProject
:eclipse
:core:eclipseClasspath
:core:eclipseJdt
:core:eclipseProject
:core:eclipse
:desktop:eclipseClasspath
:desktop:eclipseJdt
:desktop:eclipseProject
:desktop:eclipse
:html:eclipseClasspath
:html:eclipseJdt
:html:eclipseProject
:html:eclipseWtpComponent
:html:eclipseWtpFacet
:html:eclipseWtp
:html:generateGdt UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201 contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 12s
18 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 3 up-to-date
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: From the highlighted part, it seems like you are running/building with a JRE instead of a JDK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't caused by a wrong libgdx installation.

> Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201 contains a valid **JDK** installation.

Make sure your JAVA_HOME points to a JDK instead of a JRE.

Also, it's a good idea that your JDK are the same version as what declared in the *build.gradle* found in each submodule (core, desktop, android, ios...).
You should find an entry similar to this:

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
```

So choose your JDK accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a JRE for gradle. You need to be using a JDK, it can be downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).